# Python - OOP Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, oop, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game for an assignment. It needs to use object-oriented programming.

My problem is to implement a method that checks if the board is full and restarts the game with the same players. 
I have already tried to iterate through the playing field, checking if all fields are full but with no success.

I have also some trouble with promote the winning player and promote the previous player if he selects an occupied field. I think i need to change the for loop in my main function to keep track of the player or the turn but i have no clue how.

```py
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, symbol, initial_score=0):
        self.name= name
        self.symbol= symbol
        self.score= initial_score

    def won_match(self):
        self.score+= 100

    def lost_match(self):
        self.score-= 50

    def show_score(self):
        print('Player {}: {} points'.format(self.name, self.score))

class PlayingField(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.field= [
                     [None, None, None],
                     [None, None, None],
                     [None, None, None]
                    ]

    def show_field(self):
        for row in self.field:
            for player in row:
                print('_' if player is None else player.symbol,end=' ')
            print()

    def set_player(self, x, y, player):
        if self.field[y][x] is not None:
            return False

        self.field[y][x]= player

        return True

    def full_board(self):
    for row in self.field:
        for col in row:
            if col is None:
                return False
        return True

    def check_won(self, x, y, player):
    if self.field[0][x] == player and self.field[1][x] == player and self.field[2][x] == player:
        return True
    elif self.field[y][0] == player and self.field[y][1] == player and self.field[y][2] == player:
        return True
    elif self.field[0][0] == player and  self.field[1][1] == player and self.field[2][2] == player:
        return True
    elif self.field[0][2] == player and  self.field[1][1] == player and  self.field[2][0] == player:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    name_1= input('Name of Player 1: ')
    name_2= input('Name of Player 2: ')

    players= [
              Player(name_1, 'X'),
              Player(name_2, 'O')
              ]

    field= PlayingField()

    while True:
        for player in players:
            field.show_field()

            x= int(input('Player {} choose your column: '.format(player.name))) - 1

            y= int(input('Player {} choose your row: '.format(player.name))) - 1

            if not field.set_player(x, y, player):
                print('That field is already occupied.')

            elif field.full_board():
            field.show_field()
            print('full board')
            for player in players:
                print('{}: {}'.format(player.name, player.score))
            field= PlayingField()

            elif field.check_won(player):
                field.show_field()
                print('Player {} won the game.'.format(player.name))
                print('Score')
                for player in players:
                    if field.check_won(player) == True:
                        player.won_match()
                    elif field.check_won(player) == False:
                        player.lost_match()
                    print('{}: {}'.format(player.name, player.score))
                field= PlayingField()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "I have already tried to iterate through the playing field, checking if all fields are full but with no success." This is a valid approach, *how* did it not work?

Comment: Here is a nice [Reference for tic-tac-toe](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter10.html)

Comment: you should consider a recursive solution for `check_won` rather than hard-coding the valid "complete boards". Your solution will not scale for boards of size N x N. check out the n-queens problem, it has similar logic to solving a tic-tac-toe board.

Comment: @timgeb i edited the thread, so you can see what i tried.

Comment: if you step through your full_board method step by step either with a debugger or in your head/on paper. You'll see why it doesn't work very quickly.

Comment: @chatton i don't get it how to fix

Answer (score 1):

In order to check to see if the board is full, we just need to iterate through every element and check for a non-None value.

you currently have

```
def full_board(self):
    for row in self.field:
        for col in self.field:
            if col == '_':
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

remember, self.field is a list of lists. What we want to do is examine all of the elements in all three lists.

```
def full_board(self):
    for row in self.field: # all good so far
        for col in row: # <-- now we're iterating through each list in self.field
        if col is None:
            return False   # the board is not full if there's at least one empty space
    return True  # we looked at every element and they were all occupied
```

your mistake was returning too early. In your version, you check ***one*** element, then determine a True/False value based on that. In order to check ***all*** of the elements, you need to return True after the for loop.

As for the validation of chosen location, all you need to do is continuously prompt until a position is valid.

in your while loop, you could have something like this

```
x, y = prompt_for_position()

while not pos_is_valid(x,y):
    x, y = prompt_for_position()

# now we can be sure that the chosen position is valid
```

Here, prompt_for_position can just ask the user for an x/y, and pos_is_valid can take in an x and y and tells you if it's a valid position. (i.e. None/Empty square)

Hopefully this was useful for you!

Comment: first of all thanks for you help. i edited the code. I understand what i did wrong in the full_board method, but the part beneath your explanation.. i dont understand. I tried to implement the method in my main function. It works somehow. But every time the first row is filled with symbols he returns True and i cant explain to me why. I should mention that i started coding with python two weeks ago and half of the code is from my tutor.

Comment: The indentation in your full_board method is off now. Make sure the return  True is outside both for loops. If your return True is inside one of the loops, it means it will iterate through one row/col and then return.